# Filling a list instance's MultiUser Field

Tags: list, custom-list, custom-field-types, field-definition

i created a UserMulti field inside my list's instance. Heres how i declared it.

```
  <Row>
    <Field Name ="Title">List1</Field>
    <Field Name ="aatMessage">Message place holder</Field>
    <Field Name ="aatStartDate">2012-03-01T09:39:44Z</Field>
    <Field Name ="aatEndDate">2012-03-31T09:39:46Z</Field>
    <Field Name ="aatColleague">DTM01\Mathieu.Landry</Field>
  </Row>
```

The problem i have is filling up the "aatColleague" field. Adding my user doesnt seem to work. I tried without the DTM01 and it still doesnt work. Also since i added this, the item doesnt show in the list anymore but if i remove the aatColleague field it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this but try

```
<Field Name ="aatColleague">-1;#Mathieu.Landry</Field>
```

Comment: Would you need to know the Sharepoint user id from the site's user list and have 1#;Mathieu.Landry ?

Comment: See my edited response. I just verified it via powershell. You do not need the id from userinfo list. Set the id to -1

Comment: Worked. Sorry for taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add the data in a feature activated event receiver ?  This is a lot more flexible and you can debug it too.